# Looking for stable ROM for Samsung SGH-T759

Tags: samsung, rom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Does a stable Android ROM, Ice Cream Sandwich or newer, exist for the Samsung SGH-T759? SGH-T759 is the Exhibit 4G, but the older model; the SGH-T679 is the newer model with the same name.

My phone is already rooted, but I'm unable to find a ROM for it in any of the usual places (namely, XDA).